# Javascript problems with bind

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm new to JS, and have a problem figuring out why bind makes me problems:

Here is a snippet:

```
var MyTest = function() {
  registerChannel(address, null, this._messageHandler.bind(this));
};

MyTest.prototype._messageHandler = function(msg) {      
   this._logToConsole(msg); 
};

MyTest.prototype._close = function() {

  (function(inst) {
    asyncSend(address, data, 
      function(err, reply) {
        unregisterChannel(address, inst._messageHandler.bind(inst));
      }
    );
  })(this);
}
```

The `registerChannel` method stores the callback function I passed and the `unregisterChannel` tries to verify whether this callback exists and fails because 'bind' copies the method and doesn't pass them as reference (to the best of my knowledge).

The result is that `unregisterChannel` fails because it can't find the function I passed.

How can I solve this?  apply\call ? not familiar with those...

Thank you and I hope my question did sense...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time you call `.bind` you get a new reference, so the "register" and "unregister" phases won't match because you're not passing exactly the same reference.

Therefore each object will need to retain its own copy of its bound handler, e.g.:

```
var MyTest = function() {
  this._handler = this._messageHandler.bind(this);
  registerChannel(address, null, this._handler);
};
```

and you can then pass `this._handler` to your `unregisterChannel` call.

An alternative would be to not put `_messageHandler` on the `prototype` at all, and create a new instance within the constructor:

```
var MyTest = function() {

  this._messageHandler = (function(msg) {
     ...
  }).bind(this);

  registerChannel(address, null, this._messageHandler);
};
```

Comment: Could 'apply' or 'call' also help in this case ?

Comment: @Shvalb no, they don't apply (no pun intended) - they actually invoke functions rather than create passable references.

Comment: Thank you ! you helped me a lot!